# Como diferenciar os tipos de entrada?

Tags: c, c++, tipagem, char, int

Estou utilizando o operador `typeid` para verificar as condições, onde faço o seguinte teste básico:

```
int main()
{
    cout << (typeid(int) == typeid('abc')) << endl; //TRUE
    cout << (typeid(int) == typeid(100)) << endl; //TRUE
    cout << (typeid(int) == typeid(100.40)) << "\n" << endl; // FALSE

    cout << (typeid(float) == typeid('abc')) << endl; // FALSE
    cout << (typeid(float) == typeid(100)) << endl; // FALSE
    cout << (typeid(float) == typeid(100.40)) << "\n" << endl; // FALSE

    cout << (typeid(char) == typeid('a')) << endl; //TRUE
    cout << (typeid(char) == typeid('ab')) << endl; // FALSE
    cout << (typeid(char) == typeid(100)) << endl; // FALSE
    cout << (typeid(char) == typeid(100.40)) << endl; // FALSE

    return 0;
}
```

Porém, não consegui compreender o `true` e `false` para determinadas condições, como por exemplo:

```
cout << (typeid(int) == typeid('abc')) << endl; //TRUE
cout << (typeid(float) == typeid(100.40)) << "\n" << endl; // FALSE
cout << (typeid(char) == typeid('ab')) << endl; // FALSE
```

#### Questões em dúvida:

- **a)** Se um `char` é também do tipo `int`, como diferenciar um `int` de um `char`?
- **b)** Por que `typeid(float) == typeid(100.40)` não é `true`?
- **c)** Por que `typeid(char) == typeid('ab')` não é `true`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você sabe que este operador é para ser usado com objetos polimórficos e os tipos usados não são polimórficos? E que o objetivo deste operador é obter uma informação em tempo de execução e não algo que você sabe em tempo de compilação, portanto todo esse código é inútil? E sabe que não há garantias que o operador retorne o mesmo identificador de tipo para objetos de mesmo tipo?

> a) Se um `char` é também do tipo `int`, como diferenciar um `int` de um `char`?

Isto não é verdade, a conclusão está errada. `char` é `char`, e `int` é `int`.

> b) Por que `typeid(float) == typeid(100.40)` não é `true`?

Porque `100.4` é um número do tipo `double`. O literal para um valor `float` seria `100.40f`.

> c) Por que `typeid(char) == typeid('ab')` não é `true`?

Porque o tipo `char` só pode ter um caractere, então ele foi o dado foi convertido para outro tipo, possivelmente um `int`. Isto é um comportamento não especificado pela linguagem e o compilador pode fazer como achar melhor.

Complementando de acordo com os comentários: se você já sabe qual é o tipo da variável ou expressão então não tem porque usar este tipo de operador. Ele não tem nada a ver com o conteúdo entrado, ele tem a ver com o tipo usado no código, e isto você sabe sempre em tipos básicos assim. Você só não sabe quando o tipo é polimórfico, mesmo nestes casos o tipo está sempre dentro da hierarquia possível entre eles, caso contrário será falso sempre. Todo este código postado é curioso, mas desnecessário e até inútil, pode fazer a mesma coisa sem ele.

Comment: A sintaxe é do c++, mas a ideia aqui seria o entendimento da resposta dessa função, por isso inseri a tag c também. Pois bem, como eu faço para em tempo de execução comparar os tipos primitivos? Adiciona a sua resposta que aplico a mesma como a correta.

Comment: Por que quer fazer isso? Não vi necessidade.

Comment: A intenção è fazer uso de condições para caso o tipo inserido em tempo de execução seja diferente do que eu inseri ele retorna um erro, porém è somente para aprendizagem mesmo.

Comment: Isto é impossível acontecer. O tipo é definido em tempo de compilação então não pode ser diferente em tempo de execução. Acho que não entendeu para que serve este operador. Por isso eu reforço, ele só é útil para comparações polimórficas, que não é o caso, esta é a única chance do tipo de ser diferente em tempo de execução. Não tente fazer algo que não precisa ser feito e não faz sentido fazer.

Comment: Certo, compreendi, então eu terei que utilizar o famoso switch para analisar a entrada a partir do cin? Para verificar se realmente è um número ou um char? Eu estou tentando fazer algo elegante para isto, o que sugere?

Comment: Não, não precisa, se você declarar a variável como `char` é um `char`, se declarar como um `int` é um `int`, não muda nada e você já sabe que tipo é quando está codificando, não precisa nada disto. A tipagem já está definida no seu código, o que quer fazer não faz sentido.

Answer (score 2):

> a) Se um char é também do tipo int, como diferenciar um int de um char?

O tipo `char` é um tipo diferente de `int`. Consegue comprovar apenas com o seguinte:

```
cout << (typeid(int) == typeid(char)) << endl; //0
```

Mas o `char` é representado internamente com um valor numérico correspondente à tabela ASCII. Por isso é comum de se converter o valor de um `char` para um inteiro.

O motivo pelo que no seu caso deu verdadeiro é que você construiu uma `string` ou `char` errada. O próprio compilador lhe avisa disto, quando compila o seu código:

> ...main.cpp|14|warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]|

Uma string é delimitada por `"` e pode ter vários carateres, já um char é delimitado por `'` e pode apenas ter um caratere. Você colocou vários carateres num `char` o que está errado.

> b) Por que typeid(float) == typeid(100.40) não é true?

Porque `100.40` é interpretado como `double`. Também consegue ver facilmente isto trocando o `cout` correspondente para:

```
cout << (typeid(double) == typeid(100.40)) << "\n" << endl; // 1
```

> c) Por que typeid(char) == typeid('ab') não é true?

Pelo mesmo motivo que expliquei no primeiro ponto.

[Veja os exemplos que mencionei no Ideone](https://ideone.com/KfKc4H)

Comment: Como faço para testar os tipos primitivos em tempo de execução ? Adicione isto a resposta é irei aplicar a mesma como a correta.

Comment: @THIAGODEBONIS Mas o que está a tentar fazer exatamente ? Só sabendo isso é que consigo sugerir algo.

Answer (score 0):

Sobre as questões **a)** e **c)**, a [ISO/IEC 9899:1999](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) na seção **§6.4.4.4.10** define este comportamento:

> An  integer  character  constant  has  type int.The  value  of  an 
>   integer  character  constant containing  a  single  character  that 
>   maps  to  a  single-byte  execution  character  is  the numerical 
>   value  of  the  representation  of  the  mapped  character 
>   interpreted  as  an  integer.The  value  of  an  integer  character 
>   constant  containing  more  than  one  character  (e.g.,'ab'),  or 
>   containing  a  character  or  escape  sequence  that  does  not  map 
>   to  a  single-byte execution character,is implementation-defined.  If an
>   integer character constant contains asingle character or escape
>   sequence, its value is the one that results when an object
>   with type char whose value is that of the single character or escape
>   sequence is converted to type int.

Sobre a questão **b)**, o valor 100.40 é do tipo double. Para que o mesmo seja float, o valor deve ser definido como uma literal deste mesmo tipo, posfixando-o com a letra "f": 100.40f